# Error 403 Forbidden if I go to a wordpress url that is the same of an existing directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I am developing a new site in wordpress, my site is completed and I want to replace it with my old site (not a wordpress site, a php and html site).

The moving wordpress procedure is correct (I have installed wordpress in a subdirectory), i can see everything but when i go to a page like `www.site.com/mypage` which is the same name of an existing folder in my site (www.site.com/mypage) i get the `403 error`.
in the folder there is not a index.php/html file.

I want to keep this permalink structure and the folders name..
I do not want to show the list of files in the directory, but only the page I have created in wordpress.

how can I fix it?

thank you

htaccess here:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: `mypage` id a directory or file?

Comment: Post the content of your .htaccess

Comment: `# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /wordpress/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]

</IfModule>



# END WordPress`

Comment: Do u have any other .htacccess outside that folder or inside of it? Is your folder called wordpress?

Comment: my folder is called wordpress, i have an .htaccess in the root folder, but when i move the site to the root i overwrite it with the wordpress .htaccess (pasted above)

Comment: And you want to list the content of this directory?

Comment: no, i don't want to do this, i want to display my wordpress page that has the same url of the directory

Comment: Please, [edit] your Question and add details/clarifications to it, instead of here in Comments.

Comment: i have done it.. is there a possible solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this problem and found an answer here: http://jeffreybarke.net/2011/01/wordpress-permalinks-403-forbidden-error/

In short, you need to write a few lines into your .htaccess which specify the folder names with the problem:

```
# Fix 403 errors on existing directories; WordPress overrides.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(folder1|folder2|etc)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```